# update State react hook JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update the State(JSON data).
The initial state is an empty object because will be populated with "tree"(json data) on first render( the tree data is coming from a promise, so i tried to simulate that with a useEffect).
The problem is that i don't know how to update the "val" property from "tree" with the value from each slider(target.value).

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Slider from './slider'


let data = [
  {id: 'Item 1', index: 0, name: 'Item 1'},
  {id: 'Item 2', index: 1, name: 'Item 2'},
  {id: 'Item 3', index: 2, name: 'Item 3'},
  {id: 'Item 4', index: 3, name: 'Item 4'},
  {id: 'Item 5', index: 5, name: 'Item 5'},
  {id: 'Item 6', index: 6, name: 'Item 6'},
  {id: 'Item 7', index: 7, name: 'Item 7'},
  {id: 'Item 8', index: 9, name: 'Item 8'},
  {id: 'Item 9', index: 12, name: 'Item 9'},
]
let data2 = [
  {id: 1, val: 0.5088961783678},
  {id: 2, val: 0.074147856793482},
  {id: 3, val: 0.074147856793482},
  {id: 5, val: 0.074147856793482},
  {id: 6, val: 0.074147856793482},
  {id: 7, val: 0.074147856793482},
  {id: 0, val: 0.097068824077823},
  {id: 9, val: 0.074147856793482},
  {id: 12, val: 0.074147856793482},
]

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({})


  function handleChange(index, value) {
    setValues() 
  }

  
  let tree = {}
    data2.forEach((v) => {
      tree[v.id] = (v.val * 100).toFixed()
    })
    

  
  React.useEffect(() =>{
    setValues(tree)
  },[])

    
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <Slider
          key={item.id}
          value={values[item.index]}
          title={item.name}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e.target.value)}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: You're trying to show multiple sliders?

Comment: I’m already doing this by mapping through the data array.

Comment: What is the relationship between tree and data array?

Comment: The “val” from tree should be assigned to the slider that matches the index from data. Ex: the val with id:0 should be assigned to the slider that have index 0. I have already done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the state like this:

```
function handleChange(index, value) {
  setValues((prevState) => {
     return { ...prevState, ...{[index]: value}};
  });
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-davinci-p5d7k?file=/src/App.js:992-1125

Comment: Thanks man. 
Could you help me to modify this function: 
  function handleChange(index, value) {
    const remaining = 100 - parseInt(value, 10)
    setValues((vs) =>
      vs.map((v, i) => {
        if (i === index) return parseInt(value, 10)
        const oldRemaining = 100 - parseInt(vs[index], 10)
        if (oldRemaining) return (remaining * v) / oldRemaining
        return remaining / (sliders.length - 1)
      }),
    )
  }

So that will work also now when the state is an json ?

Comment: Basically this function is splitting the total value in equal mode to all sliders. When one slider is moving, automatically the value of the other sliders will change( always sum 100 max).
First time the state was an array, so i could map through the values, but now it’s an json and i have no idea how to do it. 
Here is an example with the previous sliders(with the array): 

https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-rosalind-0hiyl?file=/src/index.js&codemirror=1

Comment: Could you post this formatted in a new question? As you can see code comments are pretty unreadable (it's totally ok and encouraged on this site to split different problems into multiple questions)

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I posted it here as an answer. I hope its ok

Answer (score 0):

How could i make this function work with a JSON:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(
    new Array(sliders.length).fill(100 / sliders.length),
  )

  function handleChange(index, value) {
    const remaining = 100 - parseInt(value, 10)
    setValues((vs) =>
      vs.map((v, i) => {
        if (i === index) return parseInt(value, 10)
        const oldRemaining = 100 - parseInt(vs[index], 10)
        if (oldRemaining) return (remaining * v) / oldRemaining
        return remaining / (sliders.length - 1)
      }),
    )
  }
```

Basically this function is splitting the total value in equal mode to all sliders.
When one slider is moving, automatically the value of the other sliders will change( always sum 100 max).
First time the state was an array, so i could map through the values, but now it’s an json and i have no idea how to do it.

Here is an example with the previous sliders(with the array): https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-rosalind-0hiyl?file=/src/index.js&codemirror=1